# Как получить строку из json файла

Tags: java, парсер, gson

Мне нужно из json файла достать строку:

- из объекта;

  - из массива массивов;

(надеюсь правильно понимаю).

Каким образом именно 7 индекс получить?

желательно через Gson.

[image: Скрин json'a]

Comment: Создать экземпляр Gson. Отдать ему JSON, получить объект в виде Листа Листов Map  (Строка, Число).

Comment: @DimXenon, можно пример? Не понял каким образом это должно выглядить

Comment: Закинул в ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На скорую руку:

```
public static void someMethod() {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = "{'ts':11111111,'updates':["
            + "[4,22599,532497,200000004,1524945269,'Nulls Chant','H',{'from':85763899}],"
            + "[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]]}";
    MyObject o = (MyObject)gson.fromJson(json, MyObject.class);
    List<Object> objects = o.getUpdates().get(0);
    System.out.println(objects);
    System.out.println(objects.get(7));
}

public static class MyObject {
    Long ts;
    List<List<Object>> updates;

    Long getTs(){
        return ts;
    }

    List<List<Object>> getUpdates(){
        return updates;
    }
}
```

Дальше можно самостоятельно "причесать".

Answer (score 1):

Это простой код для этого, я избегал всех проверок, но это основная идея.

```
 JsonElement jsonElement = new JsonParser().parse(json);
 JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
 jsonObject = jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("object");
 JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("updates");
 jsonArray = jsonArray.get(0).getAsJsonArray();
 jsonObject = jsonArray.get(7).getAsJsonObject(); 
 int result = jsonObject.get("from").getAsInt();
```

Чтобы сделать использование более универсальным - вы обнаружите, что документация по [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) довольно ясна и полезна.