# Java проверить, что JSON не содержит вложенных объектов

Tags: java, json

Как можно проверить, что объект JSONObject не содержит вложенных JSON-объектов?

То есть объект вида

```
{
    "first" : "1",
    "second" : "2"
}
```

должен быть валидным, а объект вида

```
{
    "first" : "1",
    "inner" : {
        "inner-field" : "data"
    }
}
```

должен быть невалидным.

Моя попытка последовать одному из советов:

```
package json;

import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import org.junit.Test;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;

public class TestNested {
    @Test
    public void testHasNestedJSON() {
        final String nested = "{ \"data\" : \"test\", \"inner\" : { \"key\" : \"inn\"} }";
        System.out.println(nested);
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        System.out.println(parser.parse(nested).getClass());
    }

    @Test
    public void testPlainJSON() {
        final String plain = "{ \"data\" : \"test\" }";
        System.out.println(plain);
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonElement jsonElement = parser.parse(plain);
        JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
        System.out.println(jsonElement.getClass());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо распарсить JSON (например с помощью `JsonParser`), затем посмотреть тип возвращаемого объекта. Как распарсить json можно посмотреть [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/821167/204920).

> ```
> new JsonParser().parse(json);
> ```

Comment: Как посмотреть тип и какую информацию надо искать, чтобы определить вложенность?

Comment: Тип можно посмотреть с помощью `getClass()`. Чтобы определить вложеннсть, возвращаемый тип не должен быть примитивным, т.е. вы можете смотреть если тип `JsonObject `, то у вас есть вложенность.

Comment: у меня тип JsonObject получается всегда: одинаково для JSON с вложенностью и без

Comment: значит вы делаете что-то не так

Comment: можете посмотреть, что именно я делаю не так? Код добавил в свой пост.

Comment: нужно смотреть на вложенный объект