# как распарсить json в java без использования библиотек?

Tags: java, json

пример json файла:

```
{
  "Person": [
    {
      "age": 14,
      "name": "Master"
    },
    {
      "age": 15,
      "name": "Master2"
    },
    {
      "age": 15,
      "name": "Master3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Без использования библиотек - это как, вы хотите руками парсинг формата написать с нуля?

Comment: Конкретно такой файл/строку?  Или общий случай?  На какой ответ вы рассчитываете?  В чём проблема с использованием библиотек?

Comment: например как достать первого человека и вывести его имя и возраст

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как получить строку из json файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/821139/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7-json-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0)