# Как задать имя JSONObject

Tags: java, json

есть код

```
  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    jsonObject.put("id", "1");
                    jsonObject.put("qty", "1");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

он выводит

```
{
"id" : 1,
"qty" : 1
}
```

а нужно получить вывод

```
{"list": [{
"id" : 2,
"qty" : 11
}]}
```

как это реализовать?

Comment: `JSONObject` - это словарь, а есть еще `JSONArray`

Comment: Но туда ведь через put нельзя вставить имя + велью, там только через индекс @gil9red

Comment: Что-то подобное я реализовал [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/821167/204920).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Как задать имя?

Вы его задаете когда кладете что-то в JSONObject

```
jsonObject.put("id", "1");
```

Вот сейчас вы "*задали имя*" полю `id`
Абсолютно также вы задаёте имена всем остальным полям.
Если нужно - вкладываете одни JSONObject в другие и даете нужные имена полям

#### Как получить то что на примере?

**все просто:**

- создайте еще один корневой элемент
- создайте JSONArray в котором будет храниться список объектов
- положите этот JSONArray в корневой элемент
- а в JSONArray добавьте элемент созданный ранее

**рабочий пример:**

```
try {
    // создаем корневой элемент
    JSONObject rootJson = new JSONObject();
    // создаем массив json объектов
    JSONArray listJson = new JSONArray();
    // создаем элемент списка
    JSONObject itemObject = new JSONObject();

    // заполняем элемент списка
    itemObject.put("id", 2);
    itemObject.put("qty", 11);

    // кладем его в JSONArray
    listJson.put(itemObject);
    // который в свою очередь кладем в корневой элемент в поле list
    rootJson.put("list", listJson);

    // приводим к строке и выводим
    System.out.println(rootJson.toString());

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

output

```
{"list":[{"qty":11,"id":2}]}
```